# Linux Shell Script Input

Tags: linux, shell, variables, input

I'm trying to tell a shell script information this way (when I execute it via SSH):

```
bash myscript.sh 'input1' 'input2' 'input3'
```

However I've no idea on how to convert the inputs 1, 2 and 3 into variables in shell script,
like `$var1`, `$var2` and `$var3`.

Anybody know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple, the arguments passed are held in their respective numbers:

```
input1 would be on $1
input2 would be on $2
input3 would be on $3
```

And if I recall it correctly `$0` is the script path/filename

And you can for example do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "arg1='$1' - arg2='$2' - arg3='$3'"
var1="$1"
var2="$2"
var3="$3"
echo "var1='$var1' - var2='$var2' - var3='$var3'"
```

Not really needed but just to illustrate.

Comment: Does it need to be like `$var1="$1"
$var2="$2"
$var3="$3"`?

Comment: @user2248259 you can directly use $1 instead of assigning it to a variable.

Comment: I know, but I need to convert $1 to $var1

Comment: @user2248259 then you have to use `var1="$1"` just like I did on the example above.

Comment: Shell is not Perl; the dollar sign is only needed to expand the variable to its value, not to assign to it.